# TabHost layout and DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I read about [android data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) and want to use it in my application,
but I failed on xml layout stage.

I have `activity_main.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
</data>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/tab1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</layout>
```

and tab1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
<EditText
...
```

I want apply data binding to the last `EditText`, but if I insert

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
   </data>
   <TabHost>
   ...
```

this causes

```
activity_main.xml:9: AAPT: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
```

The question is, how should I combind data binding and `TabHost` to bind `EditText` in included layout?

[Here is repo with code from question](https://github.com/davemilter/TabHostDataBinding)

Comment: Why have you not closed any of your tags?

Comment: show us full xml

Comment: @Salman500 here you can find xml from question https://github.com/davemilter/TabHostDataBinding/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout

Comment: @Codebender Why I should? Code in question illustrate problem, close tag not help to show problem. Full code is available via link at the end of question.

Comment: It's your responsibility to create a [mcve] within the question itself. Use the Lint tool and read its output. Duplicate attribute is a self explanatory error

Comment: Notice you defined `xmlns:android` twice, for example. Compare your xml line by line to the documentation. Copy the example and get it running, if you must

Comment: @cricket_007 I checked out the project and your comment fixes the problem. Now the question has a bounty. Would you like to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your hint `XML: duplicate attribute`. It even tells you a line number in the error message, 9, which is roughly within the TabHost element.

Now, which XML attribute is duplicated? The namespace (`xmlns:android`)

Remove the one that is not at the very top element of the XML in the layout tag

Comment: This line specifically, xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
I don't know how this question got two upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with `xmlns:android`

Just remove this `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from  and its done.

Regarding `DataBinding`, i don't think so you have even implemented it except that  tag

take `<data>` in your `activity_main.xml`

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="name"
        type="String"/>

</data>
```

Pass it with included layout

```
<include layout="@layout/tab1"
         app:name="@{name}"/>
```

Now catch that data inside your `tab1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="name"
            type="String"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:ems="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@{name}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

You are almost done, now you just need to implement binding in your activity

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
binding.setName("Email Address");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two errors I can see here, you used `xmlns` name space two times, and `tab1` id two times. Remove one namespace, and change id.**

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1" /* you used tab1 here as id*/
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/tab1"/> /* you used tab1 here as id */
```